# Hermitage Gem is not displaying my photos (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have installed paperclip gem on the back end and would like to apply hermitage gem as my front-end; however, I am producing an error of undefined method file. Unlike the tutorial I did not use :file as my attribute, I named it :photo instead. Does that make a difference or the the problem occur from something else?

Error Message

undefined method `file' for #

view:

```
<%= render_gallery_for @galleries %>
```

migration

```
class AddAttachmentToGalleries < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    add_attachment :galleries, :photo
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :galleries, :photo
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to readme https://github.com/ImmaculatePine/hermitage you should do something like this in your config/initializers/hermitage.rb

```
Hermitage.configure :posts do
  original 'photo'
  thumbnail 'photo(:thumbnail)'
end
```